# Frontier template using sr25519 - polkajsapi

Tags: polkadot-js, frontier

I just cloned [frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier) and modified the code for using H256 address following [this](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/master/docs/accounts.md)

These are my changes in ***runtime/src/lib.rs***:

```
pub type Signature = MultiSignature;

impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
    type CallOrigin = EnsureAddressTruncated;
    type WithdrawOrigin = EnsureAddressTruncated;
    type AddressMapping = HashedAddressMapping<BlakeTwo256>;
}

impl pallet_hotfix_sufficients::Config for Runtime {
    type AddressMapping = HashedAddressMapping<BlakeTwo256>;
}
```

And changes in ***node/src/chain_spec.rs***

```
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                ],
```

Then I started with [polkadotjs](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer) and get this error
[image]

```
Uncaught error. Something went wrong with the query and rendering of this component. Please supply all the details below when logging an issue, it may help in tracing the cause.

createType(AccountId):: Invalid AccountId provided, expected 32 bytes, found 20

Error: createType(AccountId):: Invalid AccountId provided, expected 32 bytes, found 20
at h (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.b1c146caef756c6c.js:50:76567)
at j.createType (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.b1c146caef756c6c.js:50:163671)
at Array.<anonymous> (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/comm.6c4b6b9d268abd8d.js:871:1214)
at D (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/comm.6c4b6b9d268abd8d.js:871:1808)
at L (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/comm.6c4b6b9d268abd8d.js:871:2164)
at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/comm.6c4b6b9d268abd8d.js:921:182
at Object.Ii [as useState] (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.542970b4dea9bb45.js:2:78769)
at t.useState (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.542970b4dea9bb45.js:2:361050)
at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/comm.6c4b6b9d268abd8d.js:921:176
at Pi (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.542970b4dea9bb45.js:2:75852)
```

Am I missing to change anything in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I will need to change the name of blockchain. It is because "frontier-template" is **ethereum** chain type [references](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/e774236407e3f3249dd0c538b71428068ddf3f7c/packages/apps-config/src/settings/ethereumChains.ts#L7)

```
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("newName"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("newName"),
    authoring_version: 1,
    spec_version: 1,
    impl_version: 1,
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    transaction_version: 1,
    state_version: 1,
};
```